# Trigger is not working properly?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Hello I exported database using datapump another schema so this synonyms must be in another new schema.

My old one is KTECH and new one is LTECH

```
DECLARE
  strSynonyms_KTECH       VARCHAR2(3000) := 'KTECH ';
  strSynonyms_LTECH   VARCHAR2(3000) := 'LTECH';
  strCommand              VARCHAR2(33865);
BEGIN
  LOOP
  FOR Synonym IN (SELECT * FROM ALL_SYNONYMS WHERE OWNER = strSynonyms_KTECH)

    strCommand := 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ' ||
               Synonym.KTECH || '.' || Synonym.SYNONYM_NAME ||
              ' FOR ' || strSynonyms_LTECH || '.' ||
               Synonym.TABLE_NAME;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strCommand;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried to run it but it shows me error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the text of the error message(s). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can export database synonyms from old schema as text file by using pl/sql or TOAD, then save the exported file as script, edit it then execute it on new schema.

by plsql developer:

[image]

by Toad:

[image]